# Assign a query result into a variable in forms6i

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, oracleforms

I have a table named 'test' that has a column named "A" and  i want to store the result of this query into a variable named "B":

```
select A from test where A = '1';
```

and i'm sure that the result is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select A into B from teste where A='1';
```